# iTerm2 just all of a sudden started asking me to reinstall git, after it had been installed for years?

Tags: macos, terminal, git

All of a sudden, out of the blue, my Macbook Air (OS 12.5.1 Monterey) just started to ask me to install `git` when I type `git status` into the terminal (iTerm2)...

Here is the error message if I say "no I don't want to install git":

```
$ git status
2022-09-21 18:44:57.936 xcodebuild[827:8036] [MT] DVTPlugInLoading: Failed to load code for plug-in com.apple.dt.IDESimulatorAvailability (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin), error = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3588 "dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability, 0x0109): Symbol not found: (_OBJC_CLASS_$_SimDiskImage)
  Referenced from: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability'
  Expected in: '/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator'" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle couldn’t be loaded., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability, NSDebugDescription=dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability, 0x0109): Symbol not found: (_OBJC_CLASS_$_SimDiskImage)
  Referenced from: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability'
  Expected in: '/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator', NSBundlePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “IDESimulatorAvailability” couldn’t be loaded.}, dyldError = dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability, 0x0000): Symbol not found: (_OBJC_CLASS_$_SimDiskImage)
  Referenced from: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability'
  Expected in: '/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator'
2022-09-21 18:44:58.157 xcodebuild[827:8036] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /System/Volumes/Data/SWE/Apps/DT/BuildRoots/BuildRoot2/ActiveBuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-21303/DVTFoundation/PlugInArchitecture/DataModel/DVTPlugIn.m:374
Details:  Failed to load code for plug-in com.apple.dt.IDESimulatorAvailability (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin)
Please ensure Xcode packages are up-to-date — try running 'xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch'.

NSBundle error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3588 "dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability, 0x0109): Symbol not found: (_OBJC_CLASS_$_SimDiskImage)
  Referenced from: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability'
  Expected in: '/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator'" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle couldn’t be loaded., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability, NSDebugDescription=dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability, 0x0109): Symbol not found: (_OBJC_CLASS_$_SimDiskImage)
  Referenced from: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability'
  Expected in: '/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator', NSBundlePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “IDESimulatorAvailability” couldn’t be loaded.}
Object:   <DVTPlugIn: 0x600000c70460>
Method:   -loadAssertingOnError:error:
Thread:   <_NSMainThread: 0x600002824140>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints:

Backtrace:
  0  0x000000010c315f81
  1  0x000000010c3154b5
  2  0x000000010c3156c1
  3  0x000000010c18c3ba
  4  0x000000010c147c73
  5  0x000000010c145a1f
  6  0x00007ff81e2a0317
  7  0x00007ff81e2ad7ee
  8  0x000000010c3645a1
  9  0x000000010c33a0d8
10  0x000000010c1458a3
11  0x000000010c145af5
12  0x000000010d22af66
13  0x000000010d22a526
14  0x000000010d229919
15  0x000000010abb29a4
16  0x000000010a93520a
sh: line 1:   848 Abort trap: 6           /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -find git 2> /dev/null
git: error: sh -c '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -find git 2> /dev/null' failed with exit code 34304: (null) (errno=Invalid argument)
xcode-select: Failed to locate 'git', requesting installation of command line developer tools.
```

P.S., I just said "yes" install git, and it took about 30 minutes, and now it's asking to install it again! I just restarted my computer just in case, but it's still throwing the same message and error if I say no.

Here are two screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Why did this all of a sudden randomly start to happen, and any ideas how to fix it? I haven't downloaded anything for a while, and I'm pretty sure the OS didn't auto-update today. Maybe iTerm2 updated or something... Nope, I tried running `git status` in the Utilities > Terminal app, and same deal...

Just to make it clear, `git status` has been working *for years* on my Macbook Air, and I haven't changed anything recently. So something weird is happening. I have 85GB of space left on the hard drive, so it's not a space issue I don't think...

Comment: I fixed it by running `xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch`, but I have no idea why this happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Xcode installs `git` as `/usr/bin/git`, it's really just a small stub binary that calls `xcodebuild` to find and execute the real `git` binary buried deep inside the `/Applications/Xcode.app` bundle. If something's wrong with your Xcode install, this trick breaks.

If you installed Xcode from the App Store, it probably just got auto-updated to Xcode 14, which was just released last week alongside iOS 16. Xcode 14 may have had a new license agreement that needed to be acknowledged before anything Xcode-related could run. Or it may have had some other change—perhaps in how it calls Xcode-related command-line tools—that would have been fixed by Xcode's first-run initialization process.

If you don't use or care about Xcode and want a version of `git` that isn't tied into Xcode, install your own copy of `git` via Homebrew or some other means, and use that instead of the Xcode-installed `/usr/bin/git`.

By the way, this had nothing to do with iTerm2. You would have had the same problem from macOS's built-in Terminal app. The error messages you posted were all from parts of Xcode (and one Bourne shell invocation that one of the Xcode pieces made).

Comment: Funny enough, brew doesn't work without git

Comment: Launching xcode and making sure it's up to date solved the issue for me

Comment: @Moritz  I forgot about the chicken-and-egg problems of getting some of these tools onto one's system in the first place.